# Determining if saving a model is successful in Symfony

Tags: database, symfony1, model, save

How will I determine if a new model was successfully save in symfony? I checked the return value of a model. For example $ret = $model->save(); but $ret returns null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, an exception (e.g. PropelException) will be thrown if something goes wrong. Text message will look like this: `PropelException: Unable to execute UPDATE (ADD) statement...`

Answer (score 0):

you can query it after the save() method, and if the result is not empty save() has gone fine